# Can memory from /dev/shm be cached in the CPU cache?

Tags: linux, mmap, cpu-cache

When memory is frequently accessed, it's put onto the CPU cache (L1, L2, L3). However, is the same true of memory that is mmap'd to a file living in /dev/shm? I ask because I wanted to know if having it backed to a file in /dev/shm would bypass any kind of caching by the CPU, and rather letting it fall through to a cache miss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes they'll be cached in the core's L1/L2/L3 caches unless for instance the pages are marked uncached (e.g., by configuring the [PAT](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/x86/pat.txt) accordingly) or the data is accessed via streaming reads/writes.

Comment: Using streaming reads/writes doesn't mark the page as uncacheable, it just treats these lines that way.

Comment: Thanks @Leeor for pointing out. You're right my original answer was inaccurate. I've updated it.